Tkinter GUI not displaying
Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, very much a beginner;
I'm attempting to make some  code to create a very basic app but upon running the following initial code, nothing happens. The GUI doesn't appear at all, when I click the Run button nothing happens but no error messages come up either. Thank you in advance for any help.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import scrolledtext

class ReligiousTextsApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Bible and Quran Display")
        self.notebook = ttk.notebook(root)
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.bible_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.quran_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.bible_tab, title="Bible")
        self.notebook.add(self.quran_tab, title="Quran")

        self.bible_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.bible_tab, width=80, height=20)
        self.bible_text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.quran_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.quran_tab, width=80, height=20)
        self.bible_text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        
        self.load_text("Bible Text File.text", self.bible_text)
        self.load_text("Quran Text File.txt", self.bible_text)


    def load_text(self, file_path, text_widget):
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                text = file.read()
                text_widget.insert(tk.END, text)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            text_widget.insert("File not found: " + file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ReligiousTextsApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


I tried changing the file paths for the text files thinking that it was the problem but it still doesn't make anything happen.

Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

@MichaelButscher what have I formatted wrong sorry? I didn't know how to format the code that's why I put it as an image.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Code works. Can be a pycharm bad use. Right clic on file and clic Run.

Use a Simple Example: Try running a very simple Tkinter script to see if the GUI shows up. If it does, then the issue might be with the complexity of your current script.
Here’s a simple example you can try to test if the basic GUI appears:
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Test Window")
    root.geometry('300x200')  # Set default window size
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, Tkinter!")
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    


This code does produce a GUI.  What do I do for the original code?

Do this step by step to understand the problem in which part of the code


I'm attempting to make some code to create a very basic app but upon
running the following initial code, nothing happens. The GUI doesn't
appear at all

The problem can be fixed.
Add self.bible_tab.pack(...) and self.quran_tab.pack(...):
Snippet modified:
class ReligiousTextApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Bible and Quran Display')
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.notebook.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.bible_tab = tk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.quran_tab =  tk.Frame(self.notebook)                
        self.bible_tab.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.quran_tab.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.notebook.add(self.bible_tab, text='Bible')
        self.notebook.add(self.quran_tab, text='Quran')

Noted: I don't see Run()'s button. I leave that up to you.
Screenshot:

